# Duplicating dom element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, clone

I'm trying to create a function that when onclick happens, it duplicates a selected (by class name) dom element in the html in javascript.

so far I have and I'm looking to build up listItem's onclick

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("button").onclick = duplicate;
    var i = 0;
    var original = document.getElementByClassName('listItem');

    function duplicate() {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
        clone.class = "listItem"; // there can only be one element with an ID
        original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
    }
</script>

<div class="listItem">
    <div class="thumb">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <a href="#" title="More Info">More Info</a>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="button" onclick="duplicate()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: var original = document.getElementsByClassName('listItem')[0];

Answer (score 1):

Many elements can have class so the function returns a list.

```
document.getElementByClassName('listItem');
```

should be:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('listItem')[0]; //As @nevermind said first
```

Also elements have no `class` attribute, it is `.className` so

```
clone.class = "listItem";
```

should be

```
clone.className = "listItem";
```

try to search more in the internet before you go to stackoverflow. Seems you skipped some javascript lessons (:P)

Answer (score 0):

Went with this in the end

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function Clone () {
      var listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem")[0].cloneNode(true)
      var cloneListItem = listItem.cloneNode (true);
      var list = document.getElementById ("list");
      list.appendChild (cloneListItem);
  }
</script>
```